# Insert multiple objects in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

How can I insert multiple objects (such as word documents, excel spreadsheets etc..) into a word document?

The only option I've found is doing it one by one , by choosing 'insert object' option and browsing to the file location which allows to select only one item.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is simple solution for that:

1. Copy all your files to clipboard (Ctrl + C)
2. Open the word document you would like to embed your files and click the keyboard combinatin Ctrl + Alt + V [Paste Special] and choose files option and click OK.

This will copy all the chosen files into the word document as object.
The only drawback , the files will have a generic caption (something like word document 2003-2007) instead of its name. So , the manual thing you have to do is to update the document caption.

This can be achieved by, right click , choosing object , and convert option from the drop down menu, then choose 'Update icon' and update the caption there, click OK.

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

It didnt work for me on WIn10 + Word 2013
SO I downloaded this CLI tool and merged my 20+ pdfs into one pdf and then embedded that pdf into word doc

it works on Windows Command Prompt
http://sejda.org/